# NodeJS and pg-promise, catch PostgreSQL exceptions

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, pg-promise

I'm running NodeJS and pg-promise with a PostgreSQL backend.
I've created my own TRIGGER which throws an exception in some cases. Things work fine at this end.

But with pg-promise I have trouble catching the error's name.

Using this code:

```
...
.catch(function(err) {
    console.log(err);
});
```

I'm getting the following output:

```
[ { success: false,
result: 
 { [error: vote_limit_exceeded]
   name: 'error',
   length: 80,
   severity: 'ERROR',
   code: 'P0001',
   detail: undefined,
   hint: undefined,
   position: undefined,
   internalPosition: undefined,
   internalQuery: undefined,
   where: undefined,
   schema: undefined,
   table: undefined,
   column: undefined,
   dataType: undefined,
   constraint: undefined,
   file: 'pl_exec.c',
   line: '3068',
   routine: 'exec_stmt_raise' } } ]
```

I can see the name 'vote_limit_exceeded' in the context, but how do I return as a text string?

I've tried getting "close" with:

```
console.log(err[0].result);
```

But I'm not able to get the 'vote_limit_exceeded' isolated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is the standard error presentation by PostgreSQL, which has invisible property `message`, so calling `error.message` will give you the expected result.

Best yet is to log your errors like this:

```
console.log(error.message || error);
```

**Extending on your code example...**

It looks like your error context comes from the result of calling [batch](http://vitaly-t.github.io/spex/global.html#batch) function. That means in such context you can also call `error.getErrors()[0]` to get the very first error found.

So for your specific case, a safe error logging would be:

```
.catch(error => {
    if (Array.isArray(error) && 'getErrors' in error) {
        // the error came from method `batch`;
        // let's log the very first error:
        error = error.getErrors()[0];
    }
    console.log("ERROR:", error.message || error);
});
```

And of course you can easily change it to log all errors returned by method [batch](http://vitaly-t.github.io/spex/global.html#batch) instead.

This question gave me an idea about adding property `message` to the reject result. There is always a room for improvement ;)

**UPDATE**

Following this, I updated [spex.batch](http://vitaly-t.github.io/spex/global.html#batch) reject implementation to support properties `first` and `message`, for easier error handling, and released it as version [0.4.3](https://github.com/vitaly-t/spex/releases/tag/v.0.4.3). The implementation is even better than I initially intended, because both `first` and `message` support nested [batch](http://vitaly-t.github.io/spex/global.html#batch) results.

If you update `pg-promise` to version 4.1.10 (or later), then you can log such errors in a generic way:

```
.catch(error => {
    console.log("ERROR:", error.message || error);
});
```

It will always log the correct error message, even when the error comes from a nested [batch](http://vitaly-t.github.io/spex/global.html#batch) call.